# Can I copy paste the SD card and use all developed programs?

Tags: raspbian, python

I have used the NOOBs image and installed Raspbian distribution.

I have another Pi with several scripts and programs I want to recreate to the new Pi.

Can I do a simple copy of all documents from old SD to new and use all my scripts and programs?

Or Do I have to install all the software and packages again to the new Pi and copy past the code ??

Comment: Have you tried to use a USB drive to transfer them and just try them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create the image file on your SD card and restore on other SD card for use on other RPi.

for this purpose you should with one of these applications `Win32DiskImager` [in windows] or use `df-h` [in linux] or use `dd` [in MAC OS] take an image file from your SD-card, then restore this file to other SD-card. as a result all of your files will be transferred to other SD-card and it can be used in other RPi

[tutorial](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17789160-backing-up-and-restoring-your-raspberry-pis-sd-card)

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation here, e.g. how is it done?

Answer (score 4):

While the use of Win32DiskImager can be a solution as others suggested, i would suggest to take a look at piclone. Given that you are in possession of an external memory card reader, it's very straightforward to clone your sd card in whole.

I like this method because it allows to entirely clone everything in your pi, and will not cause you some of the issues that Win32DiskImager would.

For example, Win32DiskImager requires that the sd card your are copying into has to be at least the same size if not greater than the one you are copying from. The problem is that sometimes 2 "identical" sd cards may not have exactly the same capacity in reality, hence causing Win32DiskImager to fail. Have a look at this article https://liudr.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/back-up-and-clone-raspberry-pi/ for a bit more details on these issues.

I've used, and am still using piclone to clone and setup new raspberry pis as part of a data collection and display system, and helped me a lot when having to setup multiple rpi for new applciations etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where can I download piclone?

Comment: no need to download. Just type piclone on your terminal and it will launch the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into raspi-config and make sure SSH is turned on, then you can use FileZilla to simply transfer files from one to the other.  You can do this by installing FileZilla on the older unit and transfer to the new.  Or, even better, use FileZilla from a PC and make a backup copy of your important files on your hard dive.  Then use it to copy those files to the new one.

Or, you can use scp to copy files and directories individually directly between Pis.

I see the accepted answer and it is a good one, which will make an exact clone of the older system, using Win32DiskImager.  The only gotcha is if you have assigned static IP addresses then they both would end up with the same address and you would want to deconflict those.

If you use that method you can begin with a blank SD card and skip the NOOBS installation altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I ran into the same problem with the IP address and noticed it after reading your answer.